# Get /dev entry for USB on a Mac

Tags: macos, devices, block-device, usb-device

I have never used a Mac before and have no idea what I'm doing.  I need to run `dd` on a USB device to copy data off.  I plug the device in, and it shows up in `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`.  How do I find the `/dev` entry for this device?  I tried comparing `ls -R`, no dice.  I tried the advice [in this question and the linked one in its comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280716/find-devices-informations-dev-path-and-debug-usb-devices-in-cli), but no dice.  Help.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` output specify a `BSD Name` for the device? If so, prepend it with `/dev/` and you'll have a device name for your device.

For a USB storage device, the resulting name should be something like `/dev/disk2` for the whole device, and `/dev/disk2s1` for its first partition.

With `dd`, you'll probably have to use the raw access versions of the respective devices, i.e. `/dev/rdisk2` or `/dev/rdisk2s1` respectively.

If there is no entry like `BSD Name: disk2` in the `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` output, then your device might not be a USB storage device, but some other type of USB device, and you should edit your question to tell more about the exact type of the device and what you wish to achieve with it.